# How to chaining await functions together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have 3 async / await calls that depend on each other, trying to figure out how to chain them.
Hand-coded this is what it looks like

```
// list of organizations
const { orgs } = await organizations();

// list of members belonging to single organization
const { members } = await organization_members(orgs[0]['id']);

// roles belonging to a user in an organization
const { roles } = await organization_member_roles(orgs[0]['id'], members[0]['user_id'])
```

Trying to figure out how to map through this to get a list of all organizations, each with its members and each member with its roles.

So far this is where I have gotten to:

```
  const get_members = async (org) => {
    const { members } = await organization_members(org.id)
    return members
  }

(async () => {
  const members = await Promise.all(orgs.map(org => get_members(org)))
  console.log(members)
})();
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but what is wrong with your very first example? 'Chaining' is something talked about when using `.then()` but having multiple `await` statements after each other is effectively the same as `chaining`

Comment: @Evert it is missing the last step, adding roles for each member, can't seem to find a better way of achieving that.

Comment: Could you share a signature of the function you are trying to call after? Alternatively, what if we pretend the operation is not asynchronous... how would that look like? It might be easier to use that as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for

```
async function orgsWithMembersWithRoles() {
    const { orgs } = await organizations();
    return Promise.all(orgs.map(async (org) => {
        const { members } = await organization_members(org.id);
    
        return {
            org,
            members: await Promise.all(members.map(async (member) => {
                const { roles } = await organization_member_roles(org.id, member.user_id)
                return {
                    member,
                    roles,
                };
            })),
        };
    }));
}
```